# Date range in SSRS report header

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am using Date range in where clause of the SQL query which is being used in Data Set of SSRS report. Basically I am showing current week's data which is running perfect. I would like to display both dates (Moday) and (Friday) in report's Title so users can have idea which dates this report is based on.

Could you please help me how to display these 2 dates in SSRS report title ?

### This is where clause of my query

WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 4

dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  -- Returns Monday of current week
dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 4 -- Return Friday of current week

Thanks,
Nadeem

Answer (score 0):

If you declare fromDate and toDate parameters in your report then you can reference them in both your query (as @FromDate) and in the page header as Parameters!fromDate